# How do I fix the first column in an HTML table to allow horizontal scrolling?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with four columns and three rows. I want to add horizontal scroll on the table, but the first column should remain fixed.

My HTML is structured like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What CSS can I use to achieve this effect?

Comment: table into two divisions, what is that mean?? You need table structure with divs?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the final result should look like?

Comment: You can do it by div only. No need to use tables.
And technically putting td in div is wrong.

Comment: Somya@ yes i want to add horizontal scroll on the table but first col shuold remain fixed.

Comment: @user1944725: If you just want to show the user them in separate divisions, then just put borders around the first column.
That way you don't need to use divs.

Comment: table is generating dynamically col represents websites and each row represents a directory
What i need is that if the number of websites goes beyond the page display width,there should come a horizontal scroll for all columns but first columns that shows directories name should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

You could do two tables in separate divs. Check out this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTs2j/1/)** for an example.

CSS

```
#col-one {
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}
#col-two {
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="col-one">
<table width="200px" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="col-two">
<table width="600px" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>123</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>​
```

Comment: You added another table to increase the load time.

Answer (score -1):

Use `display:table` option to get it done with pure css and div.

**HTML**

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="table_row">
        <div >xzv</div>
        <div>fjgj</div>
        <div>gj g</div>
        <div>gdj hk</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table_row">
        <div >8080</div>
        <div>7808</div>
        <div>870g</div>
        <div>80hk</div>
    </div>
</div>
​
```

**CSS**

```
  body{margin:20px}
  .table{
       display:table; 
       border-top:solid 1px red; 
       border-left:solid 1px red; 
       width:100%
     }
    .table_row{
        display:table-row
     }
    .table_row div{
        display:table-cell; 
        border-right:solid 1px red; 
        border-bottom:solid 1px red
     }​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zPKBF/)**

Comment: what about browser compatibility?